# Using boto3 to add extra tags to S3 buckets

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

Currently I'm in the process of tagging every S3 bucket I have using boto3. Compared to a resource like Lambdas, doing `s3.put_bucket_tagging` overwrites any previous tags, compared to Lambdas which only add extra tags while keeping old ones. Is there a way to only add tags, rather than overwrite them?

Secondly, I have created a method to take the current tags, add the new tags on, and then overwrite the tags with those values, so I don't lose any tags. But some of these S3 buckets are created by CloudFormation and thus are prefixed with `aws:` which gives me the error `Your TagKey cannot be prefixed with aws:` when I try to take the old tags and re-put them with the new tags.

A fix for either of these to give me the ability to automate tagging of every s3 bucket would be the best solution.

Comment: Can you try a CloudFormation update, adding the new S3 bucket tags?

Comment: I will have to do that then, although some buckets are associated with a CFT, some are not, which is why I was hoping for a way to easily tag everything. I'll have to work out a way to tag buckets that aren't associated with a CFT.

Comment: You should be able to easily script applying tags to those buckets created outside of CloudFormation. And, honestly, using CloudFormation to update the tags on the other buckets is actually the proper infrastructure-as-code way to do it (assuming it actually works).

Answer (score 2):

You are out of luck. If the S3 bucket was created by a CFT, then

- You cannot add new tags or
- Add new tags and lose the tags created by CFT (then your delete stack will fail unless you exclude that S3 resource from deletion)

You can try updating the stack with new tags as suggested by @jarmod

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My account has a huge amount of buckets, so I was trying to work out a way to automatically tag buckets that way, some made with a CFT, some not.